# Table indexing with primary key

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with columns id, name, created_at and severity and the table can end up having milions of records.

I am considering to apply indexing on created_at and severity as that is what I am filtering by on UI.

I also need to have composite primary key set on id and created_at
PRIMARY KEY, btree (created_at, id) [Due to some 3rd party tool requirements]

With the above primary key setup do I just need to add a simple index on severity (as created_at is already indexed) or should I create a composite index on [created_at, severity]

Comment: That can hardly be answered without knowing the execution plans for the various cases. PostgreSQL is able to combine index scans on different indexes, but it could also be that using the primary key index alone is efficient enough. Also, the answer will depend on how important it is to speed up the query versus how many data modifications you have and how fast they have to be. Play around with realistic amounts of test data!

Comment: EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) is your best friend for performance optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html), if you are going to be filtering on those two fields together, then it's advised that you should do a multicolumn index.

As shown in the docs, if you have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
  major int,
  minor int,
  name varchar
);
```

and query often with:

```
SELECT name FROM test2 WHERE major = constant AND minor = constant;
```

then it's a good idea to index like:

```
CREATE INDEX test2_mm_idx ON test2 (major, minor);
```